# Get "Image CSS Class" value from the Advanced Options section

Tags: images, attachments, customization

By default, WordPress allows to add an extra class to the image via Advanced Options section: https://cloudup.com/cBR2yxukXm9

If I know the image (attachment) ID then how can I get this value?

I tried **[get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)** function but it did not show me that extra class. So, I am assuming I need to use an another function to retrieve the value.

Comment: get a class? if you just want to apply your style then you should simply do it as : `.custom-class { your styles here }` in your style file.

Comment: I know but I need to get the value that was added to the "Image CSS Class" field.

Comment: i think your class will be applied/called when you add this image anywhere, why you want to get the value? what you are trying to do?

Comment: Correct. This class will be added to **img** tag. I want to use this class in the caption (**figure** tag) shortcode as well.

Comment: you got your answer?

Comment: No, I did not get an answer.

Comment: then your question is unclear, edit your question ask what exactly you are trying to achieve & what you've tried so far.

Comment: can you show the code what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Advanced Options` section you are talking about the one in the `Image Details`, the modal that shows when clicking here:

[image]

that part is [tinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/), its part of the `tinyMCE` editor, none of these fields are being saved in the WordPress database:

[image]

this is just and interface to gather data that will be set in the `<img>` tag, it uses `JavaScript`, the interface is populated when you click in the image if there is any `attribute` and/or `data` that was previously set there.

so you cant use WordPress functions to get those classnames.